# What is the best way to

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list of items in a to-do list. Each time the user clicks on a checkmark, it gets added to a "completed" items list. Besides adding it to the list, I want a pop up notification to appear right after the checkmark is clicked on. I want to do this using .dialog from jqueryUI

This is the code that adds the item to the "completed" list:

```js
$('#todo-list').on('click','.done',function(e) {
    var $taskItem = $(this).parent("li");
    var $copy = $taskItem.clone();
    $('#completed-list').prepend($copy);
    $copy.hide().slideDown(); 
    $taskItem.remove();
  }
);
```

I've tried adding a nested function, but it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to add this?

```js
$('#todo-list').on('click','.done',function(e) {
    var $taskItem = $(this).parent("li");
    var $copy = $taskItem.clone();
    $(".done").dialog({
      autoOpen:false,
      show:{
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 9000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 9000
      }
    }
);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this

```
var dialog = $(".done").dialog({
                autoOpen:false,
                show:{
                  effect: "blind",
                  duration: 9000
                },
                hide: {
                  effect: "explode",
                  duration: 9000
                }
              });

  $('#todo-list').on('click','.done',function(e) {
              var $taskItem = $(this).parent("li");
              var $copy = $taskItem.clone();
              dialog.dialog( "open" );
              })
```